# Fixing foreign/special characters

Tags: r

I have a list of names with special characters and I wish to revert them back to the actual names, in this case I want to get from the below examble of;

```
Bulcs&#250; R&#233;v&#233;sz
```

to the actual name of

```
Bulcsu Revesz
```

I have a few names like this, not fussy if the accent are in the name or not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `xml2` to recover the name from the HTML entity code:

```
# input string 
input_str <- "Bulcs&#250; R&#233;v&#233;sz"

# convert
xml2::xml_text(xml2::read_html(charToRaw(input_str)))
# [1] "Bulcsú Révész"

# If there are multiple names to be converted 
input_str_vec <- c("Bulcs&#250; R&#233;v&#233;sz", "M&eacute;lissa", "Fran&ccedil;ois")

# sapply over the vector of encoded names
sapply(input_str_vec, \(str){
  
  # convert
  xml2::xml_text(xml2::read_html(charToRaw(str)))
                 
  })

# Bulcs&#250; R&#233;v&#233;sz               M&eacute;lissa               Fran&ccedil;ois 
#              "Bulcsú Révész"                    "Mélissa"                   "François"
```

Comment: Yep thats perfect. Is there anyway this can be done for a vector of 50 names or if the only way to do it just to loop through each?

Comment: Unfortunately, `charToRaw` is not vectorized but you can just ``sapply()` over the vector of names. See the updated answer.